# Spring Security with Struts 1 authentication failure error not getting displayed

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, struts-1

Spring Security with Struts 1 authentication failure error not getting displayed. Below are my configurations and login.jsp page. Login page gets displayed and success flow works fine but in failure case i am redirected to login page but error is not getting displayed. If I use standard authentication failer url error is getting displayed but with the use of ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler error is not getting displayed.

## web.xml

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Action Servlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

## spring-security.xml

```
<http disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <!-- for the static resources, apply no security access filter -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/styles/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/login.jsp" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginAction.do" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/jsp/login.jsp"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler" 
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureHandler"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="com.test.AuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="userManagementService"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg value="/forwardAction.do"></beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry>
                <beans:key>
                    <beans:value>org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException</beans:value>
                </beans:key>
                <beans:value>/jsp/login.jsp?login_error=1</beans:value>
            </beans:entry>
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>   

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

## login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html:html locale="true">
<head>
<html:base />
</head>
<body>
<form action="/admin/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
    <bean:message key="login.userName" />
    <input type="text" name="j_username" />

    <bean:message key="login.password" />
    <input type="password" name="j_password" />

    <html:submit styleClass="button" titleKey="login.button.title">
            <bean:message key="login.button.title" />
    </html:submit>

    <p class="error"><c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/></p>
    <c:remove scope="session" var="SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following simply rather than doing it with jstl

```
${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
```

Comment: Tried it with ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message} but still error is not getting displayed.